# ML.NET 10 Minute tutorial not finishing training model. Message "The thread 0xXXXX has exited with code 0"

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

The ML.NEt 10 Minute tutorial was followed and after compiling and executing the program is stuck and console is returning the following, endlessly:

```
'The thread 0x35f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).'
```

Is this normal behavior of ML.NET or is the program stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

That's a known bug when training certain models and running in in Visual Studio with F5 (attached to process):

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/2099

For now the workaround is to use Cache in the pipeline by simply adding this line of code right BEFORE adding your trainer:

```
.AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)
```

Fixes the issue in VS F5 and improves performance in many cases. ;)

Hope it helps,
Cesar