# ML.Net stuck on pretrained model Fit() method

Tags: c#, vectorization, word-embedding, pre-trained-model, microsoft.ml

there is some code example which works with Pretrained model (link to whole example page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.textcatalog.applywordembedding?view=ml-dotnet):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Text;

namespace Samples.Dynamic
{
    public static class ApplyWordEmbedding
    {
        public static void Example()
        {
        // Create a new ML context, for ML.NET operations. It can be used for
        // exception tracking and logging, as well as the source of randomness.
        var mlContext = new MLContext();

        // Create an empty list as the dataset. The 'ApplyWordEmbedding' does
        // not require training data as the estimator ('WordEmbeddingEstimator')
        // created by 'ApplyWordEmbedding' API is not a trainable estimator.
        // The empty list is only needed to pass input schema to the pipeline.
        var emptySamples = new List<TextData>();

        // Convert sample list to an empty IDataView.
        var emptyDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(emptySamples);

        // A pipeline for converting text into a 150-dimension embedding vector
        // using pretrained 'SentimentSpecificWordEmbedding' model. The
        // 'ApplyWordEmbedding' computes the minimum, average and maximum values
        // for each token's embedding vector. Tokens in 
        // 'SentimentSpecificWordEmbedding' model are represented as
        // 50 -dimension vector. Therefore, the output is of 150-dimension [min,
        // avg, max].
        //
        // The 'ApplyWordEmbedding' API requires vector of text as input.
        // The pipeline first normalizes and tokenizes text then applies word
        // embedding transformation.
        var textPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.NormalizeText("Text")
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.TokenizeIntoWords("Tokens",
                "Text"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.ApplyWordEmbedding("Features",
                "Tokens", WordEmbeddingEstimator.PretrainedModelKind
                .FastTextWikipedia300D));

        // Fit to data.
        var textTransformer = textPipeline.Fit(emptyDataView);

        // Create the prediction engine to get the embedding vector from the
        // input text/string.
        var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TextData,
            TransformedTextData>(textTransformer);

        // Call the prediction API to convert the text into embedding vector.
        var data = new TextData()
        {
            Text = "This is a great product. I would " +
            "like to buy it again."
        };
        var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(data);

        // Print the length of the embedding vector.
        Console.WriteLine($"Number of Features: {prediction.Features.Length}");

        // Print the embedding vector.
        Console.Write("Features: ");
        foreach (var f in prediction.Features)
            Console.Write($"{f:F4} ");

        //  Expected output:
        //   Number of Features: 150
        //   Features: -1.2489 0.2384 -1.3034 -0.9135 -3.4978 -0.1784 -1.3823 -0.3863 -2.5262 -0.8950 ...
    }

    private class TextData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    private class TransformedTextData : TextData
    {
        public float[] Features { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

So, in my case if I use FastTextWikipedia300D OR Glove200D OR Glove 100D pretrained models there is a stuck process which not ends even after 10 mins while run there:

> var textTransformer = textPipeline.Fit(emptyDataView);

I tried use this resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561423/5168936
But adding doesn't have any effect

> AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)

are there any ways to understand why this happened? or I use it wrong; I will be happy for any idea. thank you!

Microsoft.ML package version in Nuget is: 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot :)
to resolve this "issue" you should download word embeddings to your "..AppData\Local\mlnet-resources\WordVectors" folder;
as example adding downloaded file: glove.6B.300d.txt to that folder succeed the debug completely and Fit() works correctly without stuck process;
so, I close this question with my own answer